# Zipping java program (folder and files)

Tags: batch-file, zip

I have a java program that I would like to zip to a file simply by running a batch script. I have done this before but have sadly lost the batch file and cannot recover it.

So here goes. I have a program structure:

```
workspace\PhoneManager
    .git
    .settings
    bin
    lib
        "libraries"
    res
        "images"
    src
        "source code"
    .classpath
    .gitignore
    .project
    App.ja
    Windows_runTool.bat
```

I want to pack a set of desired files into a zip. The desired files are in this specific case `App.jar`, `Windows_runTool.bat` and `res` folder and all of it's content.

Thanks.

## EDIT

I managed to use 7-zip and add the following command to a batch script:

```
7z a PhoneManager.zip App.jar res/ Windows_runTool.bat
```

I do however want to use a .lst file in which I can add the names of the files I want to include to my command so I don't have to change the batch script in case the amount of files build up.

I tried the following:

```
7z a PhoneManager.zip filelist.lst
```

And the listfiles.lst contains the following:

```
App.jar
res/
Windows_runTool.bat
```

But that just produces an empty zip file.

Do anyone have an idea to achieve that?

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service, so try it on your own and when stuck, share your efforts and precisely describe what you have trouble with. Please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to use 7-zip and add the following command to a batch script:

```
7z a PhoneManager.zip App.jar res/ Windows_runTool.bat
```

as explained in the edit. I then went on to look around in the 7zip command list and browsing a little elsewhere and suddenly tried the following:

```
7z a -tzip PhoneManager.zip @listfiles.lst
```

Which gave me my sought for result.

Hope this helps someone else out!